# Dynamic image imports in NextJS

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I have a number of images that I'd like to statically load, to use the next `Image` component. But which image to load will depend on what the page in question needs, determined by url params. I'm hoping to make use of some of the functionality `Image` provides, but as each image has different dimensions, loading then by url seems more complicated.

For example, the total image list is something like `["a.jpg","b.jpg","c.jpg","d.jpg","e.jpg","f.jpg","g.jpg","h.jpg","i.jpg","j.jpg"]`. But if param x is 1, it may only need a, d, f, where as if param x is 2, it may need c, d, g, h.

Is there a way to use an array to first import images with the `import image_name from '@/image/path` format?